# Error : "Subquery not permitted" using stored procedure with Table Type parameter into two separate SQL tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

i am populating a generic collection of generic objects.
then loading the collection into a `DataTable`
so i could later bulk insert via  stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[InsertNewFILE_R2]
@TestPassedTable dbo.HddFolderFiles_InsertNewFILE_R2_TableType READONLY
AS BEGIN
INSERT INTO [HddFolderFiles](FileId, CurFileName, DriveL, FilePath, FolderName, FileExt, FileSize, Created)
values(
--as the passed @TestPassedTable is a clone schema from DB, 
--so it has the [RowIndex] (identity1,1)
--i later palned to check if i could just insert into [HddFolderFiles] 
--without specifying columns but for now i am having other issues
    (SELECT  FileId from @TestPssedTable),
    (SELECT  CurFileName from @TestPssedTable),
    (SELECT  DriveL from @TestPssedTable),
    (SELECT  FilePath from @TestPssedTable),
    (SELECT  FolderName from @TestPssedTable),
    (SELECT  FileExt from @TestPssedTable),
    (SELECT  FileSize from @TestPssedTable),
    (SELECT  Created from @TestPssedTable)

)
INSERT INTO [FileLookUps] (FName)
 values(
     (select CurFileName from [HddFolderFiles])
 )


--select * from [HddFolderFiles]
select * from [FileLookUps]
END
```

**C#**

the idea was to avoid the round trip for every row to update both Database tables
in one go:

```
// Comunicator has the sql command/connection/sproc name etc'
//CollectionDebugView<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter>(this.comunicator.SqlCmd.Parameters._items)).Items[0].SqlDbType
this.DRdr = parComunicator.SqlCmd.ExecuteReader(parComunicator.Meta.CommandBehavior);
```

so i did not yet tried to load it into a specific datastructure though the executed command returning a `DataReader` raises an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[InsertNewFILE_R2]
   @TestPassedTable dbo.HddFolderFiles_InsertNewFILE_R2_TableType READONLY
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [HddFolderFiles](FileId, CurFileName, DriveL, FilePath
                                              , FolderName, FileExt, FileSize, Created)
SELECT   FileId 
        ,CurFileName 
        ,DriveL 
        ,FilePath 
        ,FolderName 
        ,FileExt 
        ,FileSize 
        ,Created 
from @TestPssedTable


INSERT INTO [FileLookUps] (FName)
select CurFileName from [TmpTestTableValued1]


    select * from [FileLookUps]
END
```